# Eclipse crash on Fedora 20

Tags: java, eclipse, fedora20

I can not run Eclipse in Fedora 20 in any case, always crash.

```
java-1.7.0-openjdk
java-1.7.0-openjdk-devel
java-1.7.0-openjdk-headless

Linux * 3.12.7-300.fc20.x86_64 #1 SMP Fri Jan 10 15:35:31 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

eclipse-platform x86_64   1:4.3.1-11.fc20
```

Tried with distribution version and with downloaded version from eclipse.org

Always the same. Start eclipse Kepler and crash. 
Fast crash using eclipse marketplace.

**log:**

```
    !ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 2 1 2014-01-14 17:30:20.014
    !MESSAGE NLS unused message: LaunchConfigurationType_1 in: org.eclipse.debug.internal.core.DebugCoreMessages
    !SESSION 2014-01-15 10:55:20.259 -----------------------------------------------
    eclipse.buildId=4.3.0.M20130911-1000
    java.version=1.7.0_45
    java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
    BootLoader constants: OS=linux, ARCH=x86_64, WS=gtk, NL=es_ES
    Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.standard.product
    Command-line arguments:  -os linux -ws gtk -arch x86_64 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.standard.product

    !ENTRY org.eclipse.core.resources 2 10035 2014-01-15 10:55:58.045
    !MESSAGE The workspace exited with unsaved changes in the previous session; refreshing workspace to recover changes.
```

Very big dump, backtrace it's not usable, fedora bugzilla can not use it.

Strace output:

```
    fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFIFO|0600, st_size=0, ...}) = 0
    mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f095d66e000
    lseek(3, 0, SEEK_CUR)                   = -1 ESPIPE (Illegal seek)
    read(3, "java version \"1.7.0_45\"", 4096) = 23
    read(3, "\nOpenJDK Runtime Environment (fe"..., 4096) = 121
    close(3)                                = 0
    munmap(0x7f095d66e000, 4096)            = 0
    close(3)                                = -1 EBADF (Bad file descriptor)
    wait4(2395, [{WIFEXITED(s) && WEXITSTATUS(s) == 0}], 0, NULL) = 2395
    --- SIGCHLD {si_signo=SIGCHLD, si_code=CLD_EXITED, si_pid=2395, si_status=0, si_utime=11, si_stime=5} ---
    stat("/etc/gre64.conf", 0x7fff321cc6b0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
    stat("/etc/gre.d/gre64.conf", 0x7fff321cc6b0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
    stat("/etc/gre.conf", 0x7fff321cc6b0)   = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
    stat("/etc/gre.d/gre.conf", 0x7fff321cc6b0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
    openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib64/", O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK|O_DIRECTORY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
    getdents(3, /* 781 entries */, 32768)   = 32728
    getdents(3, /* 787 entries */, 32768)   = 32768
    getdents(3, /* 787 entries */, 32768)   = 32736
    getdents(3, /* 775 entries */, 32768)   = 32744
    getdents(3, /* 632 entries */, 32768)   = 26464
    getdents(3, /* 0 entries */, 32768)     = 0
    close(3)                                = 0
    clone(child_stack=0, flags=CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID|CLONE_CHILD_SETTID|SIGCHLD, child_tidptr=0x7f095d643a10) = 2407
    wait4(2407, CompilerOracle: exclude org/eclipse/core/internal/dtree/DataTreeNode.forwardDeltaWith
    CompilerOracle: exclude org/eclipse/jdt/internal/compiler/lookup/ParameterizedMethodBinding.
    CompilerOracle: exclude org/eclipse/cdt/internal/core/dom/parser/cpp/semantics/CPPTemplates.instantiateTemplate
    CompilerOracle: exclude org/eclipse/cdt/internal/core/pdom/dom/cpp/PDOMCPPLinkage.addBinding
    CompilerOracle: exclude org/python/pydev/editor/codecompletion/revisited/PythonPathHelper.isValidSourceFile
    CompilerOracle: exclude org/eclipse/tycho/core/osgitools/EquinoxResolver.newState
    No bp log location saved, using default.
    [000:000] Cpu: 15.75.2, x2, 2200Mhz, 3954MB
    [000:000] Computer model: Not available
    [000:001] Browser XEmbed support present: 1
    [000:001] Browser toolkit is Gtk2.
    [000:001] Using Gtk2 toolkit
    No bp log location saved, using default.
    [000:000] Cpu: 15.75.2, x2, 2200Mhz, 3954MB
    [000:000] Computer model: Not available
    [{WIFSIGNALED(s) && WTERMSIG(s) == SIGSEGV && WCOREDUMP(s)}], 0, NULL) = 2407
    --- SIGCHLD {si_signo=SIGCHLD, si_code=CLD_KILLED, si_pid=2407, si_status=SIGSEGV, si_utime=5748, si_stime=480} ---
    shmctl(1343509, IPC_RMID, 0)            = 0
    munmap(0x7f0956f08000, 2166864)         = 0
    exit_group(0)                           = ?
    +++ exited with 0 +++
```

Comment: it must have generated an error log... post its content here..

Comment: You are running a 64bit machine? Log should tell more details.

Comment: I'm experiencing the same issue with oracle java "1.7.0_45"

Answer (score 9):

I was just fighting this today.

```
Fedora 20 and eclipse-platform-4.3.1-11.fc20.i686
eclipse.buildId=4.3.0.11fc20
java.version=1.7.0_51
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
```

An empty workspace and Eclipse sitting for a minute or two core dumps.
Initially Eclipse seemed to exception on a copy and paste in a Java file.

```
rpm --erase google-talkplugin-4.9.1.0-1.i386
And Eclipse is now stable. Thanks for the debug & hint.
```

Comment: This is now in the F20 FAQ: https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Common_F20_bugs#Eclipse_crashes_with_Google_Talk_plugin_installed

Comment: The same thing. Removing google-talkplugin solves the problem. But I really need the google-talk. Is there any other workaround?!

Comment: I don't have google-talkplugin installed. Why is this happening in my Fedora?

Answer (score 4):

If you don't want to uninstall google-talkplugin, this answer can help you. 
https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1043438#c3

It worked for me, with the following environtment:

- openSuse 13.1 x64
- Eclipse 4.3.2
- Oracle Java 1.7.0-51

Comment: This did the trick! Thanks. (You should add the how to directly in this question in case the link goes down)

Answer (score 2):

In my case google-talk-plugin  is causing this. Uninstall it.

Comment: There is an other alternative, less violent (if you don't use Chrome in Eclipse)

Answer (score 1):

Uninstall Google-talkplugin.

This work for me.

Comment: There is an other alternative, less violent (if you don't use Chrome in Eclipse)

Answer (score 0):

I have had Eclipse crash fairly regularly for me whilst debugging.

The following seems to have resolved it for me:

Fedora 20, KDE, System Settings -> Application Appearance ->

Changing Widget style from "Oxygen" to "GTK+ Style" has solved it for me.

References:

- https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/DIRSTUDIO-962
- https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=421073