# Eclipse Kepler crashes when I open Marketplace

Tags: linux, eclipse, java, opensuse

I am trying to use Eclipse 4.3 "Kepler" on openSUSE 13.1 KDE 4.11
Every time I go to open the marketplace under "Help>Marketplace", Eclipse crashes.

When I ran eclipse from CLI here is the output:

```
No bp log location saved, using default.
[000:000] Cpu: 6.42.7, x4, 2200Mhz, 11952MB
[000:000] Computer model: Not available
[000:000] Browser XEmbed support present: 1
[000:000] Browser toolkit is Gtk2.
[000:000] Using Gtk2 toolkit
No bp log location saved, using default.
[000:000] Cpu: 6.42.7, x4, 2200Mhz, 11952MB
[000:000] Computer model: Not available
java version "1.7.0_51"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea 2.4.4) (suse-24.13.5-x86_64)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.45-b08, mixed mode)
```

In my .log file I see a few errors, but not sure whats conflicting.

Here is my .log file: http://pastebin.com/qpjRnXLM

Any ideas?

Comment: See if there are any messages in the .log file in the workspace .metadata directory

Comment: possible duplicate of [Eclipse crash on Fedora 20](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21134508/eclipse-crash-on-fedora-20)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at solution on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21134508/eclipse-crash-on-fedora-20/21801978#21801978)

Uninstall google-talkplugin. This work for me.

Answer (score 1):

I run KDE as well and I've added this to eclipse.ini
after vmargs :

```
-Dorg.eclipse.swt.browser.DefaultType=mozilla
```

And it solved my problem